# MySql - getting the values of a column that are associated with all values from another column

Tags: mysql

I can't really express it very well but what i need is a query that would allow me to get all elements from a collumn of table A that are associated with all values from a collumn of table B. Here is an example:
Theres a table that contains restaurants and foods they have available like this:

```
restaurant   ||  food
========================
         r1  ||  f1
         r1  ||  f2
         r1  ||  f3
         r2  ||  f1
         r3  ||  f3
         r3  ||  f4
```

And then theres this table wich contains only a column of foods:

```
foods
======
f1
f2
f3
```

What i want is to get the name of all the restaurants that have all the foods from the second table available. In this example the result would be this:

```
restaurant
==========
r1
```

I have tried but i am not very experienced and i only know how to get all the restaurants that have foods that appear in the seccond table.

Any help would be aprecciated thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71eec/1)

```
SELECT restaurant FROM table1  
GROUP BY restaurant 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT food)=3;
```

Replace 3 with the number of distinct foods you have.**Or**,if you dont want to count manually

```
SELECT restaurant FROM table1  
GROUP BY restaurant 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT food)=(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT foods) FROM table2 );
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24229/18)

Comment: it worked thanks! i just had to add "where food in (select foods from table2)" before group by and its solved :) thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` in where condition to check

```
Select restaurant from table1 where food in (select foods from table2)
```

If you want to check with specific food from the second table, change the query as follow

```
Select restaurant from table1 where food = 'f1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join too: Like this:

`select a.restaurant from table1 a inner join table2 b on(a.food=b.food)`